# Restrict users from modifying datasources in SSRS

Tags: ssrs

We had a situation lately when a particular user of the SSRS reports modified the datasources defined on the reporting server. These users have access rights to create ad-hoc reports using reportbuilder. Because of this it's turning out to be tricky to manage the access using pre-defined roles.

Is there a way to restrict users form having access to modify the datasource, yet have the ability to use datasources for ad-hoc reports?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess that you are running SSRS in Native mode rather than SharePoint integrated, and that you are using the pre-defined roles to grant access to users. If you want to post more information about the version of SQL Server you are using and the security role these users are in, I can update my answer. For now, try this.

There are [pre-defined security roles in SSRS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157363.aspx#bkmk_myreports):

- Content Manager
- Publisher
- Browser
- Report Builder
- My Reports
- System Administrator
- System User

I'm going to guess that these users are currently in the My Reports Role.  This role is allowed to do quite a bit, including manage data sources and manage reports.  This means these users can create delete, view, and modify data sources.

You might want to consider [creating a new role](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156293%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) that has only the item-level permissions you want.  You can find the list of item-level tasks [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160344%28v=sql.110%29.aspx). You basically want to include all of the item-level tasks included in the My Reports role, except Manage Data Sources. You could also modify the My Reports role to remove this one item rather than creating a new role.